# glibc / libintl: is bindtextdomain() really needed?

Tags: internationalization, gettext, glibc

The glibc manual explains that a `bindtextdomain()` call is needed as part of i18n setup because a package's message files may be installed in a directory other than glibc's.  If I assume this never happens with my package, that is my package is always installed on a system where glibc is the system libc or else with the same `--prefix` as glibc (or libintl), can I skip the call?

In other words, is there a default for the message file search path?

My reason is that it is a global initialization routine, and as such fits uneasily into a general purpose shared library.

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?